# Can I download the stackexchange app anywhere other than google play?

Tags: support

I try to download the app at the bottom on my XiaoMi 3, which is unfortunately not support Google play (although I can install it, but it seems that it is hard to start, needs to provided a bank card?) so may I ask for providing an outside link to download it?